# How to Bind extension methods in Monotouch?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm having a hard time to define the correct bindings for an IOS static library.
The include file contains some extension methods defined as:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface UIView(LayerEffects)

// set round corner
- (void) setCornerRadius : (CGFloat) radius;
// set inner border
- (void) setBorder : (UIColor *) color width : (CGFloat) width;
// set the shadow
// Example: [view setShadow:[UIColor blackColor] opacity:0.5 offset:CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0) blueRadius:3.0];
- (void) setShadow : (UIColor *)color opacity:(CGFloat)opacity offset:(CGSize) offset blurRadius:(CGFloat)blurRadius;

@end
```

The Monotouch documentation ([Binding Class Extensions](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Binding_Objective-C_Libraries#Binding_Class_Extensions)) is not very clear how to actually handle this.

Should this also be defined as an extension C# method? Or do we have to define this in the class "LayerEffects"?

**Update** Following mapping does not work:

```
[BaseType (typeof (UIView))]
interface LayerEffects{

    [Bind ("setCornerRadius:")]
    void SetCornerRadius ([Target] UIView uiView, float width);

    [Bind ("setBorder:width")]
    void SetBorder ([Target] UIView uiView, UIColor color, float width);

    [Bind ("setShadow:opacity:offset:blurRadius")]
    void SetShadow ([Target] UIView uiView, UIColor color, float opacity, SizeF offset, float blurRadius);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to define a new class to make a binding:

```
[BaseType(typeof(UIView))]
public interface UIViewLayerEffects
{

}
```

But this doesn't really help your situation.

You want to use this on any `UIView` right?

It might be easier to translate the code underneath into C#.  These methods don't look too hard to implement.  For example, I think `setCornerRadius` is just this:

```
myView.Layer.CornerRadius = 3f;
```

Comment: In this case it would indeed very easy to implement, because I actually have the objective-c code; but in case you get the .h file with a static library (.a) then it would be great to know how to creating the binding.

Comment: Also, the proposed mapping does not work - it compiles but when actually executing the method, the compiler crashes with the exception: "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: That sounds like a typo on your method name.  Can you post your binding?

Comment: Remove all the `[Target]` parameters you have, does it work then?

Comment: Removing the Target parameter did away the exception, but did not execute the underlying method...

Comment: And you are creating a new `UIViewLayerEffects` and adding it to a view?

Comment: Yes, I create a new LayerEffects class (from the binding) and executing the method (with my UIView typed class as first parameter). But nothing happens then...